# Is there any difference between "refurbish" and "renovate"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

In this week, I was following the news of the Grenfell tower and I mostly heard the verb "refurbish" being used. That triggered my curiosity to know why this verb is getting used more than "renovate".

> I am wondering if there's any significant difference between ***[refurbish](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refurbish)*** and ***[renovate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/renovate)***?

Is there any difference between these two verbs?

---

More info

I googled the difference, but the pages do not say completely similar things. For instance, you can read these references [[wikidiff](http://wikidiff.com/refurbish/renovate)], [[hinative](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/244650)], and [[wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/renovation-restoration.2039403/)].

Comment: See [_Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms_](https://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA682&dq=refurbish), a great resource for this and many similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be idiomatic or specific to American English, in which case it might not apply to the news you're seeing. But I would almost always use "refurbish" for a piece of furniture or equipment - something moveable. I would use "renovate" exclusively with a building or structure.

> I would buy a recently *refurbished* laptop or couch.
>
> I would buy a recently *renovated* house or apartment.

I don't think it's wrong to say the apartment has been refurbished; it's probably technically correct, but it sounds off to my ear.

Comment: In the UK (south) i rarely hear 'renovate' and I would consider it an American term. When people are having building work done in their house I generally hear things like: (a) I'm having some building work done (b) I've got builders in (c) I'm getting a kitchen/bathroom put in (d) I'm building an extension, etc. For large office buildings I hear things like: (a) They're doing it up (b) They're redoing all the inside. I don't think i've heard 'refurbish' in the context of interior building work either, though.

Comment: Hi, how do both word compare with *revamp*?